# C# .Net 6.0 System.IO.Ports is depricated. How can I use SerialPort?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am C# programmer and using VS 2022, with .NET Framework is no problem using `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` in order to use `.GetPortNames()` for collect available serial port list.

for example;

```
ComboBox CMS = new ComboBox();
string[] comlist = System.IO.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
CMS.Items.Clear();
//ComboBox item add if serial port is exist
if (comlist.Length > 0) CMS.Items.AddRange(comlist);
```

However, this code is not working on .NET 6.0.
`System.IO` is exist but `.Ports` does not. So Ports.SerialPort... all removed.

How can I get Serial Ports list with .NET 6.0?
I've searched and google a lot but can't find solution.

Comment: "Ports" exists too, but there is no "Ports" in your code.

Comment: What about this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding the `System.IO.Ports` NuGet package:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.IO.Ports" Version="7.0.0" />
```

Also note that the fully qualified name is `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`, not `System.IO.SerialPort`