# How to use System.IO.Ports (7) on linux?

Tags: c#, linux, nuget, serial-port

I am running dotnet 7 on an arch linux PC. When I install the IO Ports as a nuget package I get the NotSupported Exception.

[image: Platform not accepted]

When I include the dll explicitly everything works fine.
How do I tell dotnet locally that linux and unix are compatible to eachother?

[image: Platform accepted]

I am a little lost here, as all necessary dll's and so files are present in the nuget folders.

I did find a workaround ... by simply copying the dll over the base dll. But that shouldn't be the way to do it.
[image: workaround]

Comment: I would agree, but in System.IO.Ports there is a dependency on the native runtimes packages. Whcih include the linux dll's which are working fine with the workaournd. But I think a workaround shouldn't be needed. And success has been reported with this package on linux

Comment: Maybe these articles will help you. [C# .Net 6.0 System.IO.Ports is depricated. How can I use SerialPort?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75578803/9014308), [System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.IO.Ports is currently only supported on Windows. on Archlinux #79196](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/79196), [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort not working on Linux arm64 #74332](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/74332)

Comment: It is working just fine, when using the correct build parameters. Just not out of the box in JetBrains Rider.

Answer (score 1):

.NET has a concept called Runtime Identifier, which is typically values like `win-x64`, `win-arm64`, `linux-x64`, `osx-arm64`, and so on. The .NET runtime has a [RID catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) that tells it which RIDs are compatible with which other RIDs.

When you build or publish a RID specific output, then the .NET SDK will determine which assets apply to the RID, and then copy those into the output directory. Otherwise (VS shows this as "AnyCPU"), the .NET SDK will copy all the RID specific files into a `runtimes` subdirectory, and create a `project.deps.json` file, which is used by the runtime during [path probing(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/default-probing).

So, what exactly is going on in your case depends on information that you haven't provided. There are too many different scenarios to enumerate, but knowing how you run the program (`dotnet run`, or executing the binary directly from a folder? Which folder? Did you build with `-r` or `--rid` to specific a specific RID? probably more questions depending on the first answers)

Ultimately, this sounds like a RID issue to me. If you build with an IDE, then first figure out what the command line equivalent is, but it's probably `dotnet build`. Then, add `-bl` to the command line, so `dotnet build -bl`, or `dotnet build -r linux-x64 -bl`. This will write a file `msbuild.binlog`, which you can open with https://msbuildlog.com. Search for RuntimeIdentifier, and see if you can figure out what RID is being used. If it's a RID that is not part of the RID catalog, then the mapping to say that "this is is compatible with `unix`" is missing, and therefore neither NuGet, nor the .NET SDK, know to copy the package's `runtimes/unix` files. I'm not sure if it's still the case, but in the past the default RID would include the distribution name, like `ubuntu-x64`, or `alpine-x64`, because distros that use musl often need different native binaries than distros that use glibc. Although, I see `arch` and `arch-x64` in the RID catalog, but it still depends on the .NET SDK and/or .NET runtime setting it correctly

Comment: I'll try and find if I can set it in JetBrains Rider. Thanks for this pointer.